# tools for notification of new software revision

Tags: software-update

I'm wondering if there are any projects out there to create a standard for subscribing to notification of software updates in a way that can be easily aggregated (e.g. RSS feeds?), so that it's easy to check dozens or hundreds of software projects I'm interested in for new releases.

[**edit:** [moved the other half of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735445/) that was formerly here]

Answer (score 1):

[Appcasts](http://connectedflow.com/appcasting/) are one option which are used by tools like [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) and [AppFresh](http://metaquark.de/appfresh/).  There's also [PAD](http://www.asp-shareware.org/pad/), which tends more towards application description than a feed of updates.

Comment: Nice! So I just have to beg all my favorite software projects to use appcasts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Touchpine](https://touchpine.com/) to subscribe to applications you're interested in and receive updates via daily email digests which lists all new versions. There is also an API which allows you to integrate it in your software or automation tools.

Answer (score 0):

[UpdateNode](http://www.updatenode.com) is pretty fresh and a good Web 2.0 solution for managing updates. The client is cross-platform and the complete solution is free for OpenSource.