# tools for downloading software + automatically verifying integrity

Tags: data-integrity

(moved here from a combined question)

I'm wondering if there are any software tools projects to:

- create a standard machine-readable format for publishing a small metadata set = (download link + MD5 hash + optional public key and/or certificate)
- plus a browser plugin (preferably Firefox) to automatically read that data and assist in the steps of

  - downloading the software,
  - verify the downloaded software's integrity
  - add an entry to a log including this information along with what page the software was downloaded from.

[image: https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3335/3426085255_a5266b4435.jpg?v=0]

I know I manually generate the MD5 and compare the MD5 hash, but it's a very repetitive series of steps that can be error prone, and computers are great at automating things like this.

**update:** @cynoclast's answer got me curious and I ran across [this bugtrack item in DownThemAll](http://bugs.code.downthemall.net/trac/ticket/123) and [this microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hash-examples) and [this firefox idea](http://mdhashtool.mozdev.org/lfinfo.html), which at least leads me to believe other people are also thinking along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

### DownloadThemAll

It's a firefox plugin:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that's sort of what I want but it looks like you still have to enter in the MD5 hash; I'm looking for something that can parse an appropriately-designed webpage to compare the MD5 hash. But it's a start....

Comment: I don't think you'll find such a thing since there's no accepted standard that I'm aware of for placing the hash with the download link.

You could theoretically get the source of DTA and make an attempt yourself.